# PowerShell include input variable in output CSV

Tags: powershell

I was hoping someone could help with what I thought was somthing simple.  I have a PowerShell script that reads a file of email addresses then executes an Exchange O365 command and creates a CSV file.  This works great.  However, I was hoping to include in the output line the contents of the variable used in the input. In other words possibly concatenate it to the output of the command.

```
$Emails = Get-Content "C:\Allqueue.csv"

foreach ($Email in $Emails) {
    Get-MoveRequest $Email |
        select displayname, alias, UserPrincipalName |
        Export-Csv -Append "C:\AllqueueResults.txt"
}
```

Unfortunately, the `Get-Mailbox` results do not include the email address, so it can't be used in the select statement.

My initial attempt was to just add `$Email` to the select statement like this.

```
select displayname, alias, UserPrincipalName, $Email
```

But that just created a column.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new column with the email address with a calculated property:

```
select displayname, alias, UserPrincipalName, @{n='Email';e={$Email}}
```